# Связь между UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Доброе утро, вечер, день. Мой вопрос заключается в том, как связать эллипсы на разных UserControl. То есть у меня есть два UserControl представлены в виде элементов электрической цепи (см. Скриншот)

[image: Два UserControl]

Идея заключается в том, что при нажатии правой кнопки мыши будет запоминаться один эллипс, при "отжатии" другой.

### Через window.resourse подключил UserControl (ну чтоб можно было обращаться к элементу внутри UserControl)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Ampermetr_UC}">
        <local:Ampermetr_UC x:Name="Ampermetr"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:battary_UC}">
        <local:battary_UC x:Name="Battary"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:key_UC}">
        <local:key_UC x:Name="Key"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:lamp_UC}">
        <local:lamp_UC x:Name="Lamp"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:nagrev_UC}">
        <local:nagrev_UC x:Name="Nagrev"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:resistor_UC}">
        <local:resistor_UC x:Name="Resistor"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:uzel_UC}">
        <local:uzel_UC x:Name="Uzel"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Voltmetr_UC}">
        <local:Voltmetr_UC x:Name="Voltmetr"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

### Сам  UserControl(то есть UserControl на холсте и который можно перемещать и тд)

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ic_canvas" Grid.Column="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl>

                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedControl}" MouseDown="ContentPresenter_MouseDown" MouseMove="ContentPresenter_MouseMove" MouseUp="ContentPresenter_MouseUp">
                        <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Pos.X}" Y="{Binding Pos.Y}"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>

                    </ContentPresenter>



                </ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

### Код с помощью, которого я буду строить линии между эллипсами

```
      <ItemsControl x:Name="ic_EdgeLine" Grid.Column="2">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Line X1="{Binding A.Pos.X}" Y1="{Binding A.Pos.Y}" X2="{Binding B.Pos.X}" Y2="{Binding B.Pos.Y}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

### Класс в который передаются данные об эллипсах, которые будут выделены.

```
 public class EdgeLine
  {
     public Ellipse A { get; set; }
     public Ellipse B { get; set; }
  }
```

Я разобрался, как обратится к эллипсу внутри UserControl через код "NameOfUserControl.ElementOfUsercontrol"

Вопрос заключается в том, как добавить обработчик мыши только для эллипсов этих UserControl.

Comment: Почему вы его называете всегда Usecontrol, если он Use**r**Control? Или вы имеете ввиду что-то другое?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ой, пропустил "r", я имею ввиду UserControl

Comment: @АндрейNOP Если есть время, то можете ли подсказать идею как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, создать класс, наследованный от эллипса и сделать в нем обработчик нужного события. А потом в Вашем коде использовать этот класс.